# How do I run Updatedb everyday?

Tags: locate, updatedb

How do I edit the `update.conf` at `/etc/update.conf` to run every day on Ubuntu? This would enable me to use `locate` with a very recent database.

I read [this](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=65133):

> default setting, updatedb, it has been in /etc/cron.daily and its name
> is slocate.cron if you want to run updatedb on startup, you can add
> the line updatebd to the file /etc/rc.d/rc.local.
>
> In FC4 you must edit the file /etc/updatedb.conf and set
> DAILY_UPDATE=yes.

But that is for Fedora.

Comment: afaik Ubuntu already does this daily?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/updatedb.8.html

> updatedb  is  usually  run  daily  by  cron(8)  to  update  the default database.

Check `/etc/cron.daily`. It should be there.

---

```
/etc/cron.daily$ ls *loc*    
mlocate
```

Comment: sure but `crontab -e` doesn't show me a line that does `updatedb`. How do I access that? Not to meddle with it but to see what its all about?

Comment: Why would it be in crontab -e? That's old skool ;) daily events should go into /etc/daily

Comment: I checked and my system doesn't have a file or folder called `daily` under `/etc`

Comment: @drn cron.daily and its a directory.

Comment: For others that find this, you're probably looking to edit /etc/cron.daily/mlocate.cron, and specifically this line in it that calls updatedb: /usr/bin/updatedb -f "$nodevs"

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 it is now `plocate`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Rinzwind answer

> updatedb is usually run daily by cron(8) to update the default
>   database.

Now back to your demand:

> if you want to run updatedb on startup

you can use cron for this job, run the command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Add the following:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/updatedb
```

Save and exit.

Now this ensures that you'll update the mlocatedb on every startup of your system, in addition to its scheduled everyday.

You can comment the line containing `mlocate` in `/etc/cron.daily`  to stop the usual schedule everyday.

Comment: Do these cron jobs still run as Ubuntu uses systemd nowadays?

Comment: Oh there seems to be handled by anacron.timer.

Comment: @jarno Cron still works on Ubuntu and is installed by default, it's just that there isn't much that is handled by it by default any more.