# How to remove desktop entry of eclipse neon

Tags: 16.04, eclipse

I am trying to remove Eclispe desktop entry.
I manually added this eclipse.desktop file as i was not able to see the icon of eclipse.

Now I am trying to uninstall eclipse. I used the following code to locate eclipse.desktop file using this command:

```
locate eclipse.desktop
```

I got the following as result.

```
/home/protocol/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

So I tried to remove the following file using this command:

```
root@jeeva:/home/protocol/.local/share/applications# rm -rf eclipse.desktop
```

After executing the above command still iam able to see this file when i use the above `locate` command.

When trying see file permissions:

```
ls -l /home/protocol/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
ls: cannot access '/home/protocol/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop': No such file or directory
```

Please help me to remove the file.

Comment: check in `/usr/share/applications`

Comment: @suraj icant see the file in that directory

Comment: is there a write permission on that file? https://askubuntu.com/questions/419610/permission-of-a-desktop-file

Comment: @suraj when i try to check file permissons it gives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is deleted. Check [man page of locate](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locate.1.html).

It refers a db to search the file listed.

> The file name databases contain lists of files that were on the
>          system when the databases were last updated.

The database has not been updated yet. You can of course try [updatedb](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/updatedb.1.html)

```
sudo updatedb
```

I suggest Use [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) instead to search through your directories.

```
find /home/protocol -type f -name eclipse.desktop
```

Comment: How often is this database updated?

Comment: it is set in cron https://askubuntu.com/questions/203597/how-do-i-run-updatedb-everyday

Comment: @suraj after updating i cant see the file thank you